# Titanium and Testflight won't work together

Tags: android, ios, titanium, appcelerator, testflight

Here's the case:
I'm building an app and distributing it for beta-testers through Testflightapp.com.
Testflight provides a useful SDK, from which you can detect the user's interactions in the app.
The problem is, that although I've implemented the SDK as every tutorial/guide/forum-thread says, I'm not recieving any data..

[Here's](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4CW3EdP6GwvYl9tN0VxWWR4eGc/edit?usp=sharing) the data from the file running the testflight sdk. I've tried both the com.0x82.testflight-sdk-module from Titanium's own module-site and the NappTestflight-module (https://github.com/viezel/NappTestFlight).

What am I doing wrong?

(I've tried changing the guid of the app to the app-token and running it with normal guid)

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I use this module to [talk with TestFlight.](https://github.com/dasmurphy/testflight-module)

Setup was simple, and it is free. You need to check inside your App on TestFLight to get the correct id.